# WCF consume whilst being consumed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, client

As a student employee I have to set up a three layered project.

1) Client for the customer

2) Server for the customer's network

3) Server running on my company's network

(everything runs over a tcp connection)

The client consumes the service on the customer's network, which in it's turn consumes the service on my company's network.

I can perform a WCF connection between the client and the middle server, and a WCF connection between the middle server and the company server.

However, when the customer's service tries to consume the company's service whilst being consumed by the client, I get an error at the client.

Error:
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.

Client:

```
var client = new ClientServiceClient();
client.SendData(new Data() { ClientId = "0", AppId = "0", Area = "Area", Subject = "Testing..", Project = "BugService", Priority = "3", AssignedTo = "JCA" });
```

Middle service:

```
public void SendData(Data data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.Subject);
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    var client = new ServiceClient();
    client.SendData(data);
    Console.WriteLine("2");
}
```

Company's service:

```
public void SendData(Data data)
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
    var actions = DatabaseClient.GetActions(data.ClientId, data.AppId);
    Console.WriteLine("2");
    var report = new Report {Data = data};
    Console.WriteLine("3");
    report.CallPlugins(actions);
    Console.WriteLine("ClientId: {0}, AppId: {1}, Action: {2}, Subject: {3}", data.ClientId, data.AppId, actions, data.Subject);
}
```

The middle service only prints the subject and "1", not "2".
The company's service prints nothing.

Any help will be MUCH appreciated!
Sorry for the long post.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I made a stupid mistake.

In my config file, I was using at both the client and services tags the same port in the address..

```
<client>
        <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8523/Service" binding="netTcpBinding"

....

<services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="ClientService.ServiceBehavior" name="Service.ClientService">
            <endpoint address="" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
```